# wxpython span gridbagsizer in staticBox

Tags: wxpython, gridbagsizer

I try to format a form using GridBaxSizer within a StaticBox.
The grid has 2 rows and 4 columns, the input-fields with TextCtrl should use 3 cols and expand over the available space.

The span in tc1 and tc2 and the expand - flag does not have any influence on the width of tc1 and tc2. They appear only on the right hand side in the box.

I dont see where is the problem.
Can someone help?

Here's the code:

```
import wx

class GbsTest(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):    
        super(GbsTest, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(800, 600))

        self.InitUI()
        self.Show()     

    def InitUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()

        box = wx.StaticBox(panel, label='Demo')
        boxSizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(box, wx.VERTICAL)

        gbs = wx.GridBagSizer(2, 4)

        text2 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Name")
        gbs.Add(text2, pos=(1, 0), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP, border=10)

        tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        gbs.Add(tc1, pos=(1, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.EXPAND)

        text3 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Package")
        gbs.Add(text3, pos=(2, 0), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP, border=10)

        tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        gbs.Add(tc2, pos=(2, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.EXPAND)

        gbs.AddGrowableCol(0)
        boxSizer.Add(gbs, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        sizer.Add(boxSizer, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)

        sizer.AddGrowableCol(0)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    GbsTest(None, title="GBS-Test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Don't have time for an answer right now, `gbs.AddGrowableCol(1)` NOT `gbs.AddGrowableCol(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are defining `gbs.AddGrowableCol(0)`.
You are using column zero in `gbs` for the text that you are outputting and not the `TextCtrl` fields, which are in column 1.
Given that the text fields do not have the `wx.EXPAND` attribute you weren't seeing the issue.
Change `gbs.AddGrowableCol(0)` to `gbs.AddGrowableCol(1)` and it function as you require.